# can't transfer file to my mobile from laptop using bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

hi m new here n to ubuntu also n i have a query that is about bluetooth i can't transfer mp3 file to my mobile n m using ubuntu 14.10.The screen reads "GDBus.Error.org.openobex.Error.failed:unable to find service record" although i can transfer file from my mobile to it.

Comment: 14.10 is still in development, its not stable yet and not supported on this site.  I'd recommend you install either 12.04 or 14.04 which are supported. You could report this as a [Bug on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/107450) however.